# Negation of the statement without negation symbol

Tags: logic, solution-verification, quantifiers

The statement is :

$\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\exists y \in \mathbb{R}, (x\geq y \Rightarrow \frac{x}{y}=1)$.

I think the negation without negation symbol will be as follows :

$\exists x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}, (x\geq y \Rightarrow \frac{x}{y} \neq 1)$.

Is it correct.

And also the statement seems false as $x=0$ is counterexample.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not. The negation of $A\implies B$ is $A\wedge\neg B$. So, the negation of your statement is$$\exists x\in\Bbb Z,\forall y\in\Bbb R,\left(x\geqslant y\wedge\frac xy\ne1\right).$$And the original statement is true: if $x\in\Bbb Z$, take $y>\max\{x,0\}$. Then both $x\geqslant y$ and $\frac xy=1$ are false, and therefore $x\geqslant y\implies\frac xy=1$.

Comment: Sir which statement is true? original one or negated one? I think original one is false because for $x=0$, $\frac{x}{y}$ is always $0$.

Comment: The original statement. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Sorry but I am confused about this particular case of $x=0$. How $0\geq y \Rightarrow \frac{0}{y}=1$?

Comment: That's *not* what is being stated here. What is being stated here is that $(\exists y\in\Bbb R),0\geqslant y\implies\frac xy=1$. Which is true: take, say, $y=1$, and then both statements $0\geqslant y$ and $\frac xy=1$ are false. Therefore, for this $y$, $0\geqslant y\implies\frac xy=1$.